# Getting time series graph for 'On' and 'Off status' with help of google charts

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, graph, google-visualization

I have a production line that have two states 'On' and 'off'. I have the data when the production line is 'On' and for how long. the data is in following format

```js
data= [[new Date("2017-09-11T10:58:14.580+03:00"),8],
[new Date("2017-09-11T10:59:22.013+03:00"), 16],
[new Date("2017-09-11T11:13:23.344+03:00"), 18],
[new Date("2017-09-11T11:14:00.608+03:00"), 6],
[new Date("2017-09-11T11:14:18.877+03:00"), 20],
[new Date("2017-09-11T11:14:29.214+03:00"), 16]];
```

So the first element in the array shows the time when(Time) the production line is 'On' and the second element shows the number of seconds for which it was 'On'. 
Now I want a graph that can show the 'On' status for the desired amount of seconds like the one below. How can this be achieved with google charts or any other. Any help is appreciated[image]

P.S:Write now I managed to get a line chart but that is not the write depiction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to get the shape you need using google charts,

you will need 5 rows of data per data point

1) start the line at zero
2) move up to *ON*
3) move across the # of seconds
4) bring back down to *OFF*
5) create a break until next data point

it will also be very difficult to label the x-axis,
give the space between points

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: drawChart,
  packages: ['corechart']
});

function drawChart() {
  var data = [
    [new Date("2017-09-11T10:58:14.580+03:00"), 8],
    [new Date("2017-09-11T10:59:22.013+03:00"), 16],
    [new Date("2017-09-11T11:13:23.344+03:00"), 18],
    [new Date("2017-09-11T11:14:00.608+03:00"), 6],
    [new Date("2017-09-11T11:14:18.877+03:00"), 20],
    [new Date("2017-09-11T11:14:29.214+03:00"), 16]
  ];

  var dataTable = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  dataTable.addColumn('date', 'Time');
  dataTable.addColumn('number', 'On');

  var xTicks = [];
  data.forEach(function (row, index) {
    // add begin & end ticks
    xTicks.push(row[0]);
    xTicks.push(new Date(row[0].getTime() + (row[1] * 1000)));

    // add rows
    // start line at 0
    dataTable.addRow([row[0], 0]);

    // move line up to 1
    dataTable.addRow([row[0], 1]);

    // move line across for number of seconds
    dataTable.addRow([new Date(row[0].getTime() + (row[1] * 1000)), 1]);

    // bring line back down to zero
    dataTable.addRow([new Date(row[0].getTime() + (row[1] * 1000)), 0]);

    // break line
    dataTable.addRow([new Date(row[0].getTime() + (row[1] * 1000)), null]);
  });

  var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart1'));
  chart.draw(dataTable, {
    chartArea: {
      bottom: 60
    },
    hAxis: {
      format: 'H:s',
      slantedText: true,
      ticks: xTicks
    },
    vAxis: {
      ticks: [
        {v: 0, f: 'OFF'},
        {v: 1, f: 'ON'},
        {v: 2, f: ''}
      ]
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart1"></div>
```